# How do I undo a change of the PDF icon provided by Microsoft Edge?

Tags: windows, icons, microsoft-edge, file-association

I've messed up my Windows 10 file associations regarding PDF file icons, and I can't undo it because I can't find the original icons.

[image]

Please give me a copy of the default Microsoft Edge PDF icon, or tell me their location. I would especially like to know about the old icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the old PDF icons here:

```
C:\Windows.old\WINDOWS\SystemApps\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\Assets\
```

Note that this is under [`C:\Windows.old\`](https://www.howtogeek.com/223821/what-is-the-windows.old-folder-and-how-do-you-delete-it/), which holds the Windows directory from before the last Windows version upgrade, and which is automatically deleted by Disk Cleanup after 30 days. Make sure to copy the icons to a folder you control.

Comment: From your last post, I can see that you had solved your issue and posted the solution. I suggest you to mark your own post as an accepted answer for this question, whenever it is available to mark the answer may help other community members in future. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: thank you, I wanted to do that but I can accept is as solved within 2 days as popus says me.